# RabbitMQ and Webjob SDK. Intentionally failing function

Tags: rabbitmq, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have a webjob that is listening to a rabbitMQ queue and will pick messages of the queue and post to another service.

However, if the service fails (returns 5xx errors or similar) I would like to put the message back into the queue and try again later.

I am using a rabbitmq extension to webjob sdk (https://github.com/Sarmaad/WebJobs.Extensions.RabbitMQ/tree/master/WebJobs.Extensions.RabbitMQ) and if I understand correctly this will happend if the webjob "function" fails. Is there a way of failing it intentionally? (Other than throwing exceptions)

From the extension source code:

```
            var result = _executor.TryExecuteAsync(new TriggeredFunctionData{TriggerValue = triggerValue}, CancellationToken.None).Result;

            if (result.Succeeded)
                _channel.BasicAck(args.DeliveryTag, false);
            else
                _channel.BasicNack(args.DeliveryTag, false, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Azure WebJob SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/663a508e8a851629c26a51e7de3af36629dfd120/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Executors/TriggeredFunctionExecutor.cs#L38), we know that the WebJobs status depends on whether your WebJob/Function is executed without any exceptions or not. We can't set the finial status of a running WebJob programmatically.

Code from TriggeredFunctionExecutor class.

```
public async Task<FunctionResult> TryExecuteAsync(TriggeredFunctionData input, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{

    IFunctionInstance instance = _instanceFactory.Create((TTriggerValue)input.TriggerValue, input.ParentId);
    IDelayedException exception = await _executor.TryExecuteAsync(instance, cancellationToken);
    FunctionResult result = exception != null ?
        new FunctionResult(exception.Exception)

        : new FunctionResult(true);
    return result;  
}
```

> Is there a way of failing it intentionally? (Other than throwing exceptions)

So the answer to your question is no. Throwing exceptions is the only way to do it.

Comment: Hm, thats unfortunate since an unhandled exception seem to trigger a restart of the webjob.